# getting nullPointer Exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Currently I am trying to learn Secondary Sort in map reduce but getting an error of null pointer exception while running my mapper. I am using this [link](https://gist.github.com/airawat/6604175)
 but while running the code I get the error. here is my callStack .

> 16/06/18 13:34:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1466235357420_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
>       Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at SecondartSort.SecondarySortSample1.SecondarySortMapper.map(SecondarySortMapper.java:22)
>         at SecondartSort.SecondarySortSample1.SecondarySortMapper.map(SecondarySortMapper.java:1)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)

and my mapper code is:

```
public class SecondarySortMapper  extends Mapper<LongWritable , Text, CustomTextInt, IntWritable> {

    private CustomTextInt nameDepname;
    private Text name;
    private Text departmentName;
    private IntWritable sal;
    public void map (LongWritable key , Text value , Context context) throws IOException , InterruptedException{

        String[] line = value.toString().split(",");

        //String depName = line[3];
        String Fullname =line[2]+line[1];
        name.set(Fullname);
        departmentName.set(line[3]);
        nameDepname.set(name,departmentName);
        sal.set(Integer.parseInt(line[4]));
        context.write(nameDepname, sal);    
    }
}
```

and data file is :

```
1,kumar,sunil,enginering,2200
2,mishra,sunil,enginering,1200
3,arora,karan,mech,1200
4,sharma,vivek,physics,2300
5,koushik,vivek,physics,1350
6,sindhu,armaan,math,2310
7,arora,armaan,math,500
8,yadav,pooja,mech,1800
9,kuthi,pooja,math,1600
10,arora,sunil,physics,1450
11,mishra,karan,enginering,3400
12,chandra,manish,physics,2300
```

kindly advice

Thanks
sPradeep

Comment: @Burrito `String[] line = value.toString().split(",");`
map function will call each line and pass it to value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually create any of the class variables. These will all be uninitialized:

```
private CustomTextInt nameDepname;
private Text name;
private Text departmentName;
private IntWritable sal;
```

For example `name` should look like:

```
private Text name = new Text();
```

Comment: Thanks @Binary Nerd , for the help . it was very silly question that i have asked .You always helped me :)